# Typo errors in a submitted paper

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have submitted a paper 3 weeks ago for a good journal + conference and I just figured out that there are small typo mistakes. It is very disappointing as I have made a great effort (who does not) to have a crystal-clear, well-written paper. 
One mistake is in a Figure (I have forgotten to define an element. It is defined later on so it is not really a problem, but still). Another one is in a sentence, where one word disappeared. And this word is important: it helps to directly understand a point in the paper, without having to backtrack in the paper. None of these mistakes impact the methodology or results of course. 
When I am reviewing a paper for a conference, I like to read something that is neat. I don't mind English mistakes or even small typo errors as English is not my main language (except when it is *very* hard to understand ofc). I will not reject a paper because it has some typo mistakes in it.

However, is it possible to get rejected for such *stupid* mistakes? To what extent such mistakes can impact the opinion of a reviewer? Does it have a potential influence on the overall paper review process?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: There are so many similar questions on this forum you could have looked at...

Comment: I understand this paper is important to you, but it does sound like you are obsessing a bit. Use this as a learning experience to be more careful next time. By the sounds of it, the paper seems to still be in review. If so, you have a lot of time to address any typos/errors.

Answer (score 1):

> ... is it possible to get rejected for such stupid mistakes?

It is possible, but very unlikely.

> To what extent such [minor] mistakes can impact the opinion of a reviewer?

Very little. (More significant or more numerous mistakes can lead to rejection.)

> Does it have a potential influence on the overall paper review process?

Very little.

---

*My answers are all subjective.*

Comment: I agree. A few errors are fine. If there was a typo in the title, or there were a million typos, then yes, it would likely bias reviewer (also subjective).